# obtener el namespace en una variable en c#

Tags: c#

Actualmente desarrollo una app en C# (capa de negocios) en donde necesito obtener en una variable de tipo string, el namespace de la funcion que se esta ejecutando.

Esto lo consigo de la sigiente manera;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test28
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string NameSpace = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().EntryPoint.DeclaringType.Namespace;
        }
    }
```

Esto funciona bien, cuando se ejecuta dentro de un proyecto de tipo aplicacon consola .Net Framework

También funciona si creo una clase aparte en el mismo proyecto, y utilizo el mismo método para obtener elnamespace.

El problema, está cuando quiero obtener el namespace en un proyecto del tipo biblioteca de clases de .Net Framework.

Si el código se ejecuta ahi, me da el siguiente error:

**

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

**

¿Alguien sabe que instrucción se debe usar para obtener el nombre del namespace en una biblioteca de clases de .Net Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo 3 opciones para obtener el namespace de una clase. Lo puedes generalizar a este codigo colocandolo en una superclase

Un ejemplo sencillo

```
namespace Starwars.Core.Force 
{
  public class LightSide
  {
    private const string StringToRemove = ".LightSide";

    public string GetNamespace1()
    {
        return this.ToString().Replace(StringToRemove, string.Empty);
    }

    public string GetNamespace2()
    {
        var type = typeof(LightSide);
        return type.Namespace;
    }

    public string GetNamespace3()
    {
        var type = this.GetType();
        return type.Namespace;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta Jose, muchas gracias, funciona muy bien desde una biblioteca de clases de .net framework. Saludos y gracias